# Is there a typo in the theorem?

Tags: semigroups, topological-semigroups

I have downloaded an article of A.D. Wallace named The Structure of Topological Semigroups, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183519418.

Theorem 2.1 in the text reads:

"Each subgroup of $S$ is contained in a maximal such and no two of these intersect."

I do not understand what this sentence means, probably because it is missing some words. Can you comment please?

Comment: There are no missing words here.  "such" = "subgroup" here, the first part is just usual Zorn, and the second part is no two maximal subgroups intersect (i.e. maximal subgroups are pairwise disjoint).  It looks a little strange until you realize "maximal subgroup" here has a different meaning than that in group theory (in particular, if $S$ is already a group, then $S$ is the unique maximal subgroup).

Comment: @user10354138, would it be equivalent to say: each subgroup of $S$ is contained in a maximal subgroup, and maximal subgroups of $S$ are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent.